# Does -1 always mean "max" in SQL Server metadata table?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, character, metadata, maxlength

When running this in SQL Server, I'm seeing -1 defined in the CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH column for table fields/columns with a data type of nvarchar(max).  If the length is not defined, can I assume this is always set to -1?

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME,DATA_TYPE,CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH,IS_NULLABLE,ORDINAL_POSITION 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE COLUMN_NAME LIKE 'Ancestor_C%'
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this thread](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1240828-338-1.aspx#bm1240898), if it is `char, varchar, nchar, nvarchar` it is `MAX`:

```
...
CASE WHEN t.NAME IN ('char','varchar','nchar','nvarchar')
     THEN CASE WHEN c.max_length = - 1
               THEN 'MAX'
               ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR(4), CASE WHEN t.NAME IN ('nchar','nvarchar') THEN c.max_length / 2
...
```

According to [this site](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/183/informationschemacolumns/) it indicates:

> -1 for xml and large-value type data. Otherwise, NULL is returned.

Which is also supported by [this site](http://sqlintegrity.blogspot.com/2012/07/sql-server-hint-on-max-size-in-data.html)

[image]

Comment: looks like that first site was missing varbinary ... but your screen shot (and the database I'm using) has -1 defined for varbinary(max) for that data type as well